# Pandas: Sum multiple columns, but write NaN if any column in that row is NaN or 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column in a pandas dataframe that sums the total of other columns. However, if any of the source columns are blank (NaN or 0), I need the new column to also be written as blank (NaN)

```
a    b    c    d    sum

3    5    7    4    19
2    6    0    2    NaN    (note the 0 in column c)
4    NaN  3    7    NaN
```

I am currently using the pd.sum function, formatted like this

```
 df['sum'] = df[['a','b','c','d']].sum(axis=1, numeric_only=True)
```

which ignores the NaNs, but does not write NaN to the sum column.

Thanks in advance for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` your 0 to `np.nan` then pass `skipna = False`

```
df.replace(0,np.nan).sum(1,skipna=False)
0    19.0
1     NaN
2     NaN
dtype: float64
df['sum'] = df.replace(0,np.nan).sum(1,skipna=False)
```

Comment: That worked, thanks so much! I clearly have a lot to learn about pandas, so I appreciate the help!